# making 100% li width in a vertical

Tags: html, css

can someone help me with my problem , i want to make a li take 100% Width of a Div

right now it looks like this

[image: pic1]

i want it to take 100% of the width of blue panel when i hover to it , can someone help me with this problem?

the Blue Panel css

```
.sideservice{
width : 20%;
height : 100%;
background-color: rgba(72,61,180,0.8);
position: absolute;
top : 0%;
right : 0%;
padding :5px;
}
```

the li css

```
.sidemenu li{
list-style: none;
padding: 10px 10px;
margin: auto;
color: white;
width : 100%;
display:inline-block;
position: relative;
}
```

the ul css

```
#service_categories{
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Could you post your HTML? and are you using any CSS like bootstrap that may be adding styling to the ul elements aside from your styling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List elements always come with some padding. Make sure to remove that and your LI element will get its 100% width.

```
ul{
    padding:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/10b7crok/

Comment: I was just about to post that myself :)